# what is going on under the hood so this concurrent usage of a map is racy

Tags: go

in below example, the race detector will trigger an error. I am fine with it, though, as it does not change keys, the map header (if i might say), i struggle figuring out what is the reason of the race. I simply dont understand what is going on under hood so that a race detection is emitted.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// scores holds values incremented by multiple goroutines.
var scores = make(map[string]int)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    scores["A"] = 0
    scores["B"] = 0
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            // if _, ok := scores["A"]; !ok {
            //  scores["A"] = 1
            // } else {
            scores["A"]++
            // }
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            scores["B"]++ // Line 28
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Final scores:", scores)
}
```

Comment: I guess this answer fix your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511833/4994352 and more info on the map in golang https://dave.cheney.net/2018/05/29/how-the-go-runtime-implements-maps-efficiently-without-generics

Comment: @AlexandreCatalano no I am not seeking for the way to fix this. I already know how to synchronize access  to this resource.

Comment: @Inian yes i know about what you are refering to. I have taken that example in regards to what we can do using slices. Please try https://play.golang.org/p/9aImwG6joYg

Comment: The runtime is free to rearrange map contents in memory with every update, regardless of whether the key exists or not. I seem to remember reading somewhere that this allows for optimizations (moving frequently accessed elements to the beginning of their bins, for instance). Unfortunately I can't for the life of me find a link to that statement.

Comment: see also and particularly https://stackoverflow.com/a/49202499/4466350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map values are not addressable, so incrementing the integer values requires writing them back to the map itself.

The line

```
scores["A"]++
```

is equivalent to

```
tmp := scores["A"]
scores["A"] = tmp + 1
```

If you use a pointer to make the integer values addressable, and assign all the keys before the goroutines are dispatched, you can see there is no longer a race on the map itself:

```
var scores = make(map[string]*int)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    scores["A"] = new(int)
    scores["B"] = new(int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            (*scores["A"])++
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            (*scores["B"])++
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Final scores:", scores)
}
```